# Is $X = \{0,1,...,9\}^{\mathbb N}$ totally disconnected?

Tags: general-topology

Consider X with the product topology and $\{0,1,...9\}$ with the discrete topopogy.

I already attempted to prove and disprove it, both without success, so I'd be happy to know whether it is true or not, and of course I am alo thankful for any hints that might help.

Comment: Yes, it’s true. $X$ has an even stronger property: it’s zero-dimensional, meaning that it has a base of clopen sets.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** What is a subbasis for the product topology? What is a basis for the product topology?

Comment: Do you mean the subbasis that consists of preimages $\pi_i^{-1}(U)$ of open sets $U\subset X_i$ of the cannonical projections $\pi_i : X \to X_i$? (Do you agree that $X$ is totally disconnected?)